# Sorting opening hours in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have a an array with opening hours structured like this:

```
array:7 [
  "mon" => array [
    "open" => null
    "close" => null
  ]
  "tue" => array [
    "open" => null
    "close" => null
  ]
  "wed" => array [
    "open" => "09:00"
    "close" => "20:00"
  ]
  "thu" => array [
    "open" => null
    "close" => null
  ]
  "fri" => array [
    "open" => "14:00"
    "close" => "17:00"
  ]
  "sat" => array [
    "open" => "12:00"
    "close" => "15:00"
  ]
  "sun" => array [
    "open" => "12:00"
    "close" => "15:00"
  ]
]
```

I would like to create a structure like this:

```
array [
  array [
        "mon" => array [
          "open" => null
          "close" => null
        ]
        "tue" => array [
            "open" => null
            "close" => null
        ]
    ]
    array [
        "wed" => array [
            "open" => "09:00"
            "close" => "20:00"
        ]
    ]
    array [
        "thu" => array [
            "open" => null
            "close" => null
        ]
    ]
    array [
        "fri" => array [
            "open" => "14:00"
            "close" => "17:00"
        ]
    ]
    array [
        "sat" => array [
            "open" => "12:00"
            "close" => "15:00"
        ]
        "sun" => array [
            "open" => "12:00"
            "close" => "15:00"
        ]
    ]
]
```

Where days with the same opening hours are grouped together as long as the days are in a row. Otherwise a day should end up by itself.

I've been working on achieving this in PHP and this is what I've got so far.

```
$hours = []; 
$previousDay = null;

foreach ($days as $key => $day)
{   
    if ($day === $previousDay)
    {
        $hours[] = array($key => $day); 
    }
    else 
    {
        $hours[] = array($key => $day); 
    }

    $previousDay = $day; 
}
```

I'm stuck on how to group days with the same opening hours together in one array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is below?

```
$result = array();
$previous = null;
$idx = -1;
foreach ($days as $key => $day){
    if($day !== $previous){
        $idx++;
    }
    $result[$idx][$key] = $day;
    $previous = $day;
}
```